# Applied and received ESTA. Now want to delete Facebook: Problems with CBP?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I applied and was granted an ESTA a couple of months ago. I am planning to travel from the UK to NYC for a one-week holiday in just over two months. The new ESTA application asks you for your "Online presence," and I gave my Twitter handle and Facebook username.

I now want to delete Facebook: I just kept it to use Messenger on a phone which was stolen last week, and haven't really used it for the past year and a half since I switched to Twitter. I am now locked out of Messenger because for some reason I can't log back in from my new phone. I therefore have no reason to keep using Facebook. I also don't like how Facebook uses your personal information, and I have too many friends who I don't really engage with. Will deleting Facebook now, after receiving an ESTA, cause me any problem with the DHS/CBP?

(Giving out social media handles in your ESTA is optional, but I figured that the US authorities knew I had them anyway.)

Comment: Would it hurt you to keep the account till after your upcoming travel to the USA?

Comment: Do you think it would made a difference? I've already started to remove stuff like friends I don't engage with or groups that I don't participate in any more... It's also that the new interface is so poor it makes navigating the website a pain! I'd rather just delete the whole thing that go through it.

Comment: I do not know but I think it would not hurt to have an unused account, and when asked about it you can explain it as you did here.

Comment: When you *delete Facebook* your account is marked for deletion. The information is likely not swiped for some time.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem deleting your account. You are not required to keep it (or have one to begin with). If anyone asks, you just tell them you deleted it, and that’s it.